# Ordering of the lists' data by user region

Tags: ordering

We are implementing a portal using SharePoint 2010 for the company which has hierarchical regional structure. All company regions are contained in list and all users and all content have a link to this the item in this list. All data contains in the one site.
We need to display lists data to the user ordered following way:
1) Data related to the current user's region;
2) Data related to the central office;
3) Data related to the other regions.
Is it possible to implement such ordering using standard SharePoint abilities? Or what is the best way to implement such ordering if it is impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simplest approach you can use 3 CQWP:

1. it'll get data for user's region (in query option you can specify a page field, for example, which will be required for filter)
2. will simply get data from central office location
3. will get data from other regions (using field specified in the 1st step and excluding values in the filter)

[image: CQWP available tokens]

So the only thing you are required to do is to place user region's identifier in a correct place.